# Including the same shock with different share in Bartik instrument

Tags: regression, causality

Suppose I'm interested in the causal effect of $x$ on $y_i$, where $i$ is the unit of analysis that could either be individual, county, or state level. Suppose $x$ is randomly assigned to unit $d$, where $d$ is not the unit of analysis. You can think about the standard Bartik (or shift-share) instrument setting where $d$ is the industry, and $x_d$ is the random shock on industry $d$. Note I'm not interested in the instrument part, and I'll abstract away from instrument for this question.

To link the effect of shock $x_d$ on $y_i$, I utilize another variable $s_{i,d}$ which you could think about the 'share' of the variable. This 'share' is not exogenous. I can then set up a shift-share variable on the unit of analysis $i$:

$ss_i = \sum\limits_{d} s_{i,d} x_d$

I can then run a regression:

$y_i = \beta_o + \beta_1 ss_i + \varepsilon_i$

Typically, I can interpret the coefficient $\beta_1$ as a weighted causal effect of $x$ on $y$.

However, I'm wondering if I could run the following regression:

$y_I = \beta_o + \beta_1 ss_I + \beta_2 ss_c + \beta_3 ss_s + \varepsilon_i$

where $ss_I$ is the shift-share variable at the individual level, $ss_c$ is the county level, and $ss_s$ is the state level, and $y_I$ is at the individual level.

Because the causal statement is coming from the exogeneity of $x$, it seems like all $\beta$ coefficients here estimate causal inference. I believe each $\beta$ coefficient estimates how shock $x_d$ affects $y_I$ via the unit of analysis, controlling for its effect via other unit of analysis. However, I don't feel comfortable including the same shock just with different aggregation of share in the same regression. How can I interpret the causal coefficient here?